# Is there a way to pass an argument to a setter

Tags: c#

Is there a way to pass an argument to a setter?
How would I pass a string into the setter below?
How would I call the setter with the new string param?

```
public string It
{
   get{ { return it;}

   set { it = value;}
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 11):

The setter gets `value` as its own "argument", based on the value you assign to the property:

```
foo.It = "xyz"; // Within the setter, the "value" variable will be "xyz"
```

If you want to use an extra parameter, you need an *indexer*:

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get { /* Use key here */ }

    set { /* Use key and value here */ }
}
```

You'd then access it as

```
foo["key"] = "newValue";
```

You can't give indexers names in C#, or use named indexers from other languages by name (except in the case of COM, as of C# 4).

EDIT: As noted by Colin, you should use indexers carefully... don't just use them as a way of getting an extra parameter just for the setter, which you then ignore in the getter, for example. Something like this would be terrible:

```
// Bad code! Do not use!
private string fullName;
public string this[string firstName]
{
    get { return fullName; }
    set { fullName = firstName + " " + value; }
}

// Sample usage...
foo["Jon"] = "Skeet";
string name = foo["Bar"]; // name is now "Jon Skeet"
```

Comment: Just to add to that. Unless the thing you are setting has some sort of indexable semantics then don't use an indexer because then anyone who maintains the code is going to wonder what on earth is going on.

Comment: Shouldn't that be return fullName; in the getter instead of return firstName; for it to return "Jon Skeet", the current code would return "Bar" surely?

Comment: @John: Yes, that was the intention. Doh! Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign it like you can assign a value to a variable:

```
It = "My String";
```

Property getters/setters are just syntactic sugar for `string get_It()` and `void set_It(string value)`

Answer (score 4):

Properties do not admit arguments in C#.

If you really need aditional information in order to se `It` correctly then the recommended solution is to implement the setter as a method:

```
public void SetIt(string value, string moreInfo) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for any property directly we can assign the value i.e., `It = "";`

Answer (score 0):

To compliment what everyone else has said in this aged thread...

Perhaps a better method would be to define a `struct` to hold the extra information you want to pass, then pass the data this way.  For instance:

```cs
struct PersonName {

    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public PersonName(string fn, string sn) {
        Forename = fn;
        Surname = sn;
    }

}

class MyPerson {

    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }

    ...

    public PersonName Fullname {
        get { return Forename + " " + Surname; }
        set {
            Forename = value.Forename;
            Surname = value.Surname;
        }
    }
}

...

    public void main() {
        MyPerson aPerson = new MyPerson;
        aPerson.Fullname = new PersonName("Fred", "Bloggs");
    }
```

Personally, though, I think this is overkill for something so minor.  Also, it then beggars the question - why wasn't the `Forename`, `Surname` pair already defined as the appropriate `struct` (`PersonName`)?

Answer (score -1):

That's the basics of C# properties:

**[Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Lets say you create an object blah that has that property:

```
Blah blah = new Blah();
blah.It = "Hello World";
String hey = blah.It;
```

The idea of properties is to wrap the calls to local variables with some more logic (and some hiding). So the syntax is similar to working with a local class variable